# Amazon polly tts SSML tags

Tags: c#, .net, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I have used in the past amazon polly to generate audio files by text. Here the code that I have used:

```
 public static void GenerateVoiceFileByAmzonApi(string VoiceName, string StrText,string FileName)
        {

            Amazon.Polly.AmazonPollyClient cl = new Amazon.Polly.AmazonPollyClient("abc", "abc", RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            Amazon.Polly.Model.SynthesizeSpeechRequest req = new Amazon.Polly.Model.SynthesizeSpeechRequest();
            req.Text = StrText;

            switch (VoiceName)
            {
                case VOICE_NAME_AMAZON_GIORGIO:
                    req.VoiceId = Amazon.Polly.VoiceId.Giorgio;
                    break;
                case VOICE_NAME_AMAZON_CARLA:
                    req.VoiceId = Amazon.Polly.VoiceId.Carla;
                    break;
                case VOICE_NAME_AMAZON_BIANCA:
                    req.VoiceId = Amazon.Polly.VoiceId.Bianca;
                    break;
                default:
                    req.VoiceId = Amazon.Polly.VoiceId.Giorgio;
                    break;
            }

            req.TextType

            req.OutputFormat = Amazon.Polly.OutputFormat.Ogg_vorbis;
            req.TextType = Amazon.Polly.TextType.Text;
            Amazon.Polly.Model.SynthesizeSpeechResponse resp = cl.SynthesizeSpeech(req);

            using (System.IO.FileStream wFile = new System.IO.FileStream(FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                resp.AudioStream.CopyTo(wFile);
                wFile.Flush();
                wFile.Close();
            }
        }
```

This code work, but sometimes I have a text with different exclamation point (!) or question point (?) but the voice not change.

In particular there are some text with a exclamation point that contain alert situations and I like that the voice simulate the human voice in these particular circustanes also.

Do you known if with SSML or other is possible do it ?

Thanks !

Comment: You could try with the emphasis tag: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/supportedtags.html

Comment: There is another solution ? emphasis don't seem exact the some thing.